# In ruby reverse string without affecting numbers in a string and don't use regex

Tags: ruby

Given a string containing letters and digits I wish to return a string that contains the letters rearranged without affecting the positions of the digits. The i<sup>th</sup> letter in the string is to become the i<sup>th</sup>-from-last letter in the returned string. A regular expression cannot be used.

Example: if the given string were

```
"hello123wor63ld"
```

the string

```
"dlrow123oll63eh"
```

should be returned.

I found a solution using a regex but cannot figure out how to solve the problem without using a regex.

Comment: I've voted to reopen as the question is perfectly clear, as evidenced by the facts that the question has 3 upvotes (to date), there are no comments asking for clarification and that all those who provided answers interpreted the question in the same way. Additional words could have been added but nothing more is needed. @gnat, if you understand what the OP is trying to do please reconsider your decision.

Comment: Harishbn, I don't understand why it should be necessary, but I took the liberty of editing your question to add some words to satisfy the closers. I trust you do not object, but it would be good if you could do a further edit to put it in your own words. @gnat, you will see that the question has been edited.

Comment: This question asked in one of the interviews.

Answer (score 6):

Here are three ways to get the job done. None mutate the original string.

```
DIGITS = '0'..'9'
str = "hello123wor63ld"
```

**#1 Single pass with swapping**

```
def doit(str)
  s = str.dup
  ifirst = -1  
  ilast = str.size
  loop do
    ifirst = (ifirst+1..ilast-2).find { |i| !DIGITS.cover?(s[i]) }
    break if ifirst.nil?
    ilast = (ilast-1).downto(ifirst+1).find { |i| !DIGITS.cover?(s[i]) }
    break if ilast.nil?
    s[ifirst], s[ilast] = s[ilast], s[ifirst]
  end
  s
end
```

```
doit(str)
  #=> "dlrow123oll63eh"
```

I list this method first because it is the most efficient, requiring a single pass through the string and a constant amount of memory beyond that used to store the string that is returned.

**#2 Remove digits, reverse, insert digits**

```
str.delete('0123456789').reverse.tap do |s|
  str.each_char.with_index { |c,i| s.insert(i,c) if DIGITS.cover?(c) }
end
  #=> "dlrow123oll63eh"
```

The steps are as follows.

```
s = str.delete('0123456789').reverse
  #=> dlrowolleh
```

Note [String#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-delete) does not mutate its receiver.

Continuing, in [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-tap)'s block,

```
s #=> dlrowolleh
```

Then,

```
enum0 = str.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "hello123wor63ld":each_char> 
enum1 = enum0.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "hello123wor63ld":each_char>:with_index>
```

The first element is generated by `enum1` and passed to the block, where the block variables are assigned values by the process of [Array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).

```
c,i = enum1.next  #=> ["h", 0] 
c                 #=> "h" 
i                 #=> 0
```

The block calculation is then performed.

```
DIGITS.cover?(c)  #=> false
```

so

```
s.insert(i,c)
```

is not executed (`s` remains unchanged). Similarly, no characters are inserted for the next four elements generated and passed to the block by `enum1`.

```
c,i = enum1.next  #=> ["e", 1] 
DIGITS.cover?(c)  #=> false
c,i = enum1.next  #=> ["l", 2] 
DIGITS.cover?(c)  #=> false
c,i = enum1.next  #=> ["l", 3] 
DIGITS.cover?(c)  #=> false
c,i = enum1.next  #=> ["o", 4] 
DIGITS.cover?(c)  #=> false
s                 #=> "dlrowolleh"
```

Now, however,

```
c,i = enum1.next  #=> ["1", 5] 
DIGITS.cover?(c)  #=> true
```

so

```
s.insert(i,c)     #=> "dlrow1olleh"
```

is executed to insert `"1"` after `"w"`. See
[String#insert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-insert).

The remaining calculations are similar.

**#2 Save indices of non-digits in and array `non_digit_idx` then map each characters to itself if it is a digit and to `non_digit_idx` if it is a non-digit.**

```
non_digit_idx = str.each_char.with_index.with_object([]) do |(c,i),a|
  a << i unless DIGITS.cover?(c)
end
str.each_char.map.with_index do |c,i|
  DIGITS.cover?(c) ? str[i] : str[non_digit_idx.pop]
end.join
  #=> "dlrow123oll63eh"
```

The steps are as follows.

```
non_digit_idx = str.each_char.with_index.with_object([]) do |(c,i),a|
  a << i unless rng.cover?(c)
end
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14]
```

This constructs an array of the indices of characters that are not digits. See [Range#cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F).

```
"hello123wor63ld"
 0         1 
 01234   890  34
```

Next,

```
  a = str.each_char.map.with_index do |c,i|
    rng.cover?(c) ? str[i] : str[non_digit_idx.pop]
  end
  #=> ["d", "l", "r", "o", "w", "1", "2", "3", "o", "l", "l", "6", "3", "e", "h"]
```

Here I map each character of `str` to itself if it is a digit, and to the character that is at index `non_digit_idx.pop` if it is not a digit.

Lastly, join the characters in the mapped array.

```
a.join
  #=> "dlrow123oll63eh"
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one way with no regex at all:

```
input = "hello123wor63ld"
output = "dlrow123oll63eh"

res =  input.chars.map{ |ch| ch.to_i.to_s == ch ? ch.to_i : ch }.then do |ary|
  chars = ary.reject{ |e| e.is_a? Integer }.reverse 
  ary.map { |e| e.is_a?(Integer) ? e : chars.shift }
end.join

res == output #=> true
```

---

Splitting the logic.

The first step converts digits to integers:

```
input.chars.map{ |ch| ch.to_i.to_s == ch ? ch.to_i : ch }
#=> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", 1, 2, 3, "w", "o", "r", 6, 3, "l", "d"]
```

The second step reverses only the chars, not the digits:

```
input.chars.map{ |ch| ch.to_i.to_s == ch ? ch.to_i : ch }
           .then { |ary| ary.reject{ |e| e.is_a? Integer }.reverse }
#=> ["d", "l", "r", "o", "w", "o", "l", "l", "e", "h"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way!

```rb
digits = ("0".."9").to_a
str = "hello123wor63ld"
rev = str.delete(digits.join).chars.reverse # ["d","l","r","o","w","o","l","l","e","h"]

str.chars.map{|c| if digits.include?(c) then c else rev.rotate!; rev.pop end } * ''
```